# REGEX_LIKE to ~*

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, postgresql, where-clause

Quick question, I found a replacement for Oracles REGEXP_LIKE, but I don't see any documentation on multiple values. Can you tell me if the oracle and Postgres statements below are the equivalent?

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(columnname, 'guarantee|standard', 'i')

WHERE columnname ~* 'guarantee|standard'
```

Comment: I am not sure, but I guess they do.  | - is an alteration in POSIX Regular Expressions
[doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both expressions are equivalent.

From [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html):

> `~*`: matches regular expression, case insensitive

From [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Pattern-matching-Conditions.html#GUID-D2124F3A-C6E4-4CCA-A40E-2FFCABFD8E19):

> `REGEXP_LIKE` performs regular expression matching
>
> [...]
>
> match param `'i'` specifies case-insensitive matching, even if the determined collation of the condition is case-sensitive.

Comment: I thought it was, but I wasn't sure about separating the two values "guaranteed and standard"